# Change the order of displayed fields of arbitrary command output

Tags: text-processing

How could I change the order of fields from a given command?

As an example take the output of `ls -l`.  By default the file name is displayed as the last field of the output.  What could I pipe that output to in order to make the file name the first field shown?

My initial thought was to use the cut command, but regardless of the order in which fields are passed to the -f option they're always outputted in the original order.

Note: I'm only using `ls -l` as an easy example, but I'd like to find a general purpose idiom that could be used for any command that outputs data in columns.  If it could also be applied to delimited data that would be great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed number of fields you can use `awk`, for example to exchage second and fourth field:

```
command | awk '{ t = $2; $2 = $4; $4 = t; print }' | column -t
```

But unfortunately `ls -l` does not have a fixed number of field (separated by spaces) because also filenames can contain spaces: this is the reason why parsing `ls -l` output is discouraged.

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have used ls -l as my example.  Thanks for the answer.